# Can we license translation software for the Quran and Hadits?

Tags: software, legal

There is software license 9 imam Hadits by *[www.lidwa.com](http://lidwa.com)* obtained copies of copyrighted works, the owner claims that no one can copy their database.

But isn't the Quran (and Hadits) itself licensed and copyrighted by Allah and Rasulullah (SAW)?

According to Islamic laws it is free to copy Quran and Hadits, but can someone claim copyright for the translation?

They translate the Arabic to Indonesian with huge effort
and what is Sharia law to copy the Indonesian translation of hadits and Quran?

Comment: I dont know if it this was addressed by scholars before but since we are in the information age we should make sure with a scholar.

Comment: so where can i ask to scholar ?

Answer (score 3):

Copyright is fairly recent phenomenon when compared with the age of the Quran and hadith.

[Copyright|History:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright#History)

> Copyright came about **with the invention of the printing press** and with wider literacy .... Charles II of England was concerned by the unregulated copying of books and passed the **Licensing of the Press Act 1662** by Act of Parliament

Hadiths are not copyright to the Prophet (saww) because they are recorded history and traditions. More like a biography. The authors of those biographies could have claimed copyright on it. But as far as we know they have not done so nor is it likely that the copyright would be intact given their age. Copyright of Quran from a religious perspective could belong to Allah, who has sent it down for the guidance of mankind, and from an areligious perspective it belongs to no one (treated like the biography of the Prophet).

Temporally (not sure if that's the correct word) speaking even if the Quran and hadith were copyrighted they are old enough that their copyrights are very likely to have expired.

[Copyright:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright)

> Typically, the duration of copyright is the author's life plus 50 to 100 years

From LindedIn:

> [Does anyone know if prayers or religious texts are subject to copyright law?](https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/2319793-88806839)

Comment/Answer:

> Generally these are **public domain** if they are **old enough**; ...

A person can however charge you for providing the copy of Quran (or any Ayat or Surah) or Hadith. But they cannot stop you from redistributing it, and only it.

But works of **translation**, **tafser** and other educationals text can be copyrighted and the author(s) can restrict its redistribution, copying etc as per their copyright.

Same comment continued:

> ... however, it is necessary to *be cautious* as each translation has a copyright. The NIV for example is copyright protected. So it would be necessary to determine which translation the prayer and/or bible verse is in.

Comment: It's important to note that straight compilations of facts (i.e. ahadith) may still fall under copyright if there's originality or creativity involved in the actual selection, even if all the facts themselves are public-domain. (Whether that's the case with the site mentioned in OP, no clue). So, for example, if someone had selectively compiled all sahih ahadith from public-domain hadith collections, *that* compilation could be copyrightable, where just "all hadith from these public-domain collections" would not be (afaik, ianal).

Comment: so is it haram if i copy and redistribution the translation without author(s) permission ?

Comment: If the author has prohibited it and you have agreed to that restriction in some form then yes, @coder5.

Comment: and they can licence/copyright software, which gives access, search capability etc to the texts, and probably also to that how they have made it beautiful, ornaments, fonts etc