# Are there any copyright restrictions on reproducing English translations of the Quran?

Tags: quran, hadith, translation

I am planning to build a simple mobile app that provide the user with extracts from the Holy Koran, collection of the Ahadith and the Sunnah.

I will be providing the Arabic text as well as the English translation and transliteration.

Are there any copyright restrictions on reproducing these English translations & transliterations?

I am intending to use the late Yusuf Ali's widely respected English translation of the Holy Koran.

Regards the ahadith and Sunnah, I have not confirmed a source yet.

I realised that a similar copyright question was asked here previously:

[Can we license translation software for the Quran and Hadits?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24696/license-of-translation-software-quran-and-hadits)

I'm just hoping for a little more information.

Comment: Check this link regarding copyrights of Yusuf Ali's translations (read the notice section) http://www.sacred-texts.com/isl/quran/

Comment: Thank you brother/sister. I have read that page already. Seems outside the USA, Yusuf Ali's works are pubic domain - i.e. not subject to copyright.